# Active record for AND in code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can i write this query in active record in codeigniter.

```
 SELECT * FROM `post_ads` WHERE `dates` >= '2014-09-20' AND `dates` <= '2014-09-22' ORDER BY `dates` ASC
```

I tried this code but gave an empty array.

```
 $where = "DATE(dates) BETWEEN '2014-09-20' AND '2014-09-22'";
    $query = $this->db->where($where)->get('post_ads');
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: no attempts whatsoever? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: $where = "DATE(dates) BETWEEN '2014-09-20' AND '2014-09-22'";
        $this->db->where($where)->get('post_ads');

Comment: i tried this but it didn't give the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply without array you can try out this where condition separated by ; creates AND operation.

```
      $this->db->where('dates >=', 2014-09-20);
      $this->db->where('dates <=', 2014-09-22);
      $this->db->order_by("dates", "asc");
       $query = $this->db->get('post_ads');
      return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simply Repeat it twice like this:**

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('post_ads');
$this->db->where('dates','2014-09-20');
$this->db->where('dates','2014-09-22');
$this->db->order_by('dates');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the codeigniter tutorials: My query worked with the following query:

```
$array = array('dates >=' => $to, 'dates <=' => $from); 
$this->db->where($array);
$this->db->order_by("dates", "asc"); 
$query = $this->db->get('post_ads');
return $query->result();
```